# Index out of range in fibonacci using dynamic programming

Tags: python, python-3.x, dynamic-programming, indexoutofboundsexception, fibonacci

Recently Dynamic Programming perked my interest. So, I wrote a code on fibonacci series using dynamic programming concept but every time on execution i am greeted with array out of index out of range. I tried hard to figure it out but couldn't fix it.
From the error I think the index goes out of bound on the last iteration. Here's my code :

```
def fibo(n) :

# len(mem) being shorter than n will indicate that the position is not filled(memoized)
# if it is equal then is has the required value it wont have to calculate res = fibo(n-1)+ fibo(n-2)
    if len(mem) == n :
        return mem[n]

#General cases
    if n == 1 or n == 2 :
        res = 1
    elif n == 0 :
        res = 0
    else :
        res = fibo(n-1)+ fibo(n-2)

#Here the len(m) should be n-1 and thus we append the value of 'res'so at one point we can return it instead of calculating
    mem.append(res)
    return res

#Start of Program
n = int(input("Enter the position :"))

#Defining mem as a list
mem = []

print(fibo(n))
```

Comment: If len(mem) >= n: return mem[n-1], because index starts at 0

Comment: provide complete error message

Answer (score 0):

You need to add 1 to your list first:

```
mem = [1]
for i in range(1,10):
    print(fibo(i))

1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
```

Comment: Your code is more like recursion to me, you can solve this problem without using recursive function.

Comment: Also your `mem` is redundant if you want to use recursion

Answer (score 0):

> but is the implementation right?

No.  Even if you include @ExplodingGayFish's fix, it hides the fact that your memoization logic is broken.  For example:

```
...
#Defining mem as a list
mem = [1]

print(fibo(5))
print(mem)

print(fibo(4))
print(mem)
```

You get the right answer, but are doing all the work over again:

```
> python3 test.py
5
[1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 5]
3
[1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 5, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3]
>
```

This is due to your mishandling of the `mem` array, including this test:

```
if len(mem) == n :
```

which really should be *greater*, not *equal*.  The solution is actually simpler than your broken code:

```
def fibo(n, memory=[0]):  # intentional dangerous default

    if len(memory) > n:
        return memory[n]

    if n == 1:
        res = 1
    else:
        res = fibo(n - 1) + fibo(n - 2)

    memory.append(res)

    return res
```

However, even with multiple calls to `fibo(900)`, a *good recursive algorithm* like the following:

```
def fibo(n, res=0, nxt=1):
    if n == 0:
        return res

    return fibo(n - 1, nxt, res + nxt)
```

will match the speed of my repaired version of your code even without memoization!  And neither will reach `fibo(1000)` without expansion of Python's stack due to recursion depth.  (Which is why a memoized iterative solution would be better.)